# error when installing nodemon on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodemon, enoent

when i install *nodemon* with

```
sudo npm i --save-dev nodemon
```

i get the following error message:

```
npm ERR! path /home/dominikpatera/Dropbox/Projekty/Fytwa/server/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/dominikpatera/Dropbox/Projekty/Fytwa/server/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev' -> '/home/dominikpatera/Dropbox/Projekty/Fytwa/server/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.abbrev.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dominikpatera/.npm/_logs/2018-07-11T09_45_21_545Z-debug.log
```

can you help me fix it?

Comment: had you take a look over `/home/dominikpatera/.npm/_logs/2018-07-11T09_45_21_545Z-debug.log` ?

Comment: you should not use sudo when installing locally. If you want it to be global, then use sudo npm i -g nodemon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open Terminal and type:

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

then

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

you will get an output similar to:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
```

After that your nodemon will perfectly work.

Comment: oh man this worked. Do you have any documentation you could link or explain why those follow-up commands were needed/set?

Answer (score 0):

At first make sure that on your terminal, you are working on the correct project. you can check this by typing `ls` and then hit enter.

Then give the command to install nodemon. From the official website of nodemon, we found that, we have to write `npm install -g nodemon`

But if you fall in problem here, then write this-

`sudo npm install -g nodemon`